# Problem while installing katoolin in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, katoolin, kali-linux-tools

```
ragib@RAGIB-PC:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ragib:
root@RAGIB-PC:/home/ragib# git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin 
fatal: destination path 'katoolin' already exists and is not an empty directory
root@RAGIB-PC:/home/ragib# chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin
root@RAGIB-PC:/home/ragib# katoolin
bash: /usr/bin/katoolin: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
root@RAGIB-PC:/home/ragib# sudo katoolin
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory
root@RAGIB-PC:/home/ragib#
```

[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6urm3.png)

I was trying to install katoolin to get all the Kali linux tools in Ubuntu 17.10. I have seen many tutorials describing same method, and I think I've done that exactly the same way, but something is not right, either in my system or I did something wrong while trying to install katoolin.

Comment: It looks like you already have leftover files in `/usr/bin/katoolin`. Remove the katoolin directory and its contents recursively using this command: `sudo rm -r /usr/bin/katoolin` and try again. Please comment or edit your question and report any errors.

Comment: btw You are already root, so you don't need to type `sudo katoolin` - `katoolin` will do instead.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run this:

```bash
sudo bash -c "test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -qqy update && apt install -qy python-minimal)"
```

Then run the command `katoolin`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update python
```

then run `katoolin`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04. You have to install python2

```
sudo apt-get install python2
```

Then open the file katoolin.py in nano or gedit and change

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

for

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

then make the cp command from the actual directory to /usr/bin/katoolin.py

```
sudo cp katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin.py
```

and with that you should be okay