# katoolin issue in Ubuntu 18.04 - "/usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, 18.04, katoolin

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.
I have installed katoolin but it does not run. I'm using below commands

```
git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo katoolin
```

but after all I'm facing below error.

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory
```

please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe `file /usr/bin/katoolin` to start?

Comment: Were there any errors when you were installing it, like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1018449/301745)?

Comment: Check the first line of `/usr/bin/katoolin`. Perhaps it points to an interpreter which isn't installed.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

```
git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/katoolin
cd /usr/bin/ # change directories to the directory where katoolin is located  
sudo ./katoolin # execute the katoolin script
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have different version on python installed and you katoolin have different version.

You have to edit this line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I have python3 so adding python3. Add your version here

1. `nano /usr/bin/katoolin`
2. `#!/usr/bin/python`
   Into
3. `#!/usr/bin/python3`
4. `sudo katoolin`

After this may be You will get error like this

```
 File "/usr/bin/katoolin", line 8
print "Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges"
      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges")?
```

If you got error like this Change this line

```
print "Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges"
```

Into

```
print ("Sorry. This script requires sudo privledges")
```

If you have different version you will get an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/bin/katoolin", line 1294, in main
    inicio1()
  File "/usr/bin/katoolin", line 41, in inicio1
    opcion0 = raw_input("\033[1;36mkat > \033[1;m")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Do like this
For Python 3.x, use `input()`. For Python 2.x, use `raw_input()`

1. Change all `raw_input` Into
2. `input` If you are a python3 users. or For python2 use `raw_input`.

If you solve your problem can you approve my answer.

Comment: If you find your solution can you approve my answer to help others.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install `python2.7`
2. update string in `/usr/bin/katoolin`

   from
   `/usr/bin/python`
   to
   `/usr/bin/python2.7`
3. run in terminal:

   `sudo katoolin`

done, it works now